# What is wrong with this compile time map?

Tags: c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm struggling to understand why I cannot typedef this map, the compiler complains

```
main.cpp:14:41: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for 'template<class ...> struct Map'
struct Map<KeyType, Key, Value, Rest...> {
                                     ^
main.cpp:14:41: note:   expected a type, got 'Key'
main.cpp:24:23: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template 
parameter list for 'template<class ...> struct Map'
typedef Map<int, 1, A> map;
```

Here is the code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

 template<typename...>
 struct Map;

 template<typename KeyType>
 struct Map<KeyType> {
   template<KeyType NotFound>
   struct get { typedef std::false_type val; };
 };

 template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key, typename Value, typename... Rest>
 struct Map<KeyType, Key, Value, Rest...> {
     template<KeyType Get>
     struct get {
         typedef std::conditional<Get == Key, Value, typename Map<KeyType, Rest...>::template get<Get>::val> val;
     };
 };

 struct A { static constexpr int value = 1; };
 struct B { static constexpr int value = 2; };

 typedef Map<int, 1, A> map;

 int main() {
   std::cout << map::get<1>::val::value << std::endl;
   //std::cout << map::get<2>::val::value << std::endl;
   //std::cout << map::get<3>::val::value << std::endl;
 }
```

It appears that somehow the first key in the map typedef is being taken as the key type, and I am not sure how that happens.

EDIT

I came to a solution, the goal is to have a compile time map from some constant value to a type, so I can map enums to types at compile time. I was able to solve the problem by wrapping the Key in a type, and passing the KeyType as the first template param to the map. Some boilerplate typedefs make it not as ugly like `template<int V> using IntMap = Map<MyKey<int, V>;` and `template<MyEnum E> using MyEnumMap = Map<MyEnum, E>`. I believe these could be made cleaner using c++17 auto templates. Please comment.

```
    #include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key>
 struct KeyValue {};

 struct KeyNotFound {};

 template<typename...>
 struct Map;

 template<typename KeyType>
 struct Map<KeyType> {
   template<KeyType Key>
   struct get { typedef KeyNotFound type; };
 };

 template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key, typename Value, typename... Rest>
 struct Map<KeyType, KeyValue<KeyType, Key>, Value, Rest...> {
     template<KeyType Get>
     struct get {
         typedef typename std::conditional<Get == Key, Value, typename Map<KeyType, Rest...>::template get<Get>::type>::type type;
     };
 };

 struct A { static constexpr int value = 1; };
 struct B { static constexpr int value = 2; };


 typedef Map<int,
     KeyValue<int, 1>, A, 
     KeyValue<int, 2>, B> map;

 int main() {
   std::cout << map::get<1>::type::value << std::endl;
   //std::cout << map::get<2>::val::value << std::endl;
   //std::cout << map::get<3>::type::value << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The forward declaration of `Map` expects to see only type parameters. You are using a non-type parameter in the specialization, which is not allowed.

That's what the compiler is complaining about.

I am unable to suggest a solution since I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with a mix of type and non-type parameters.

Comment: I understand that from the error message, but my specialization is `template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key, typename Value, typename... Rest> struct Map<KeyType, Key, Value, Rest...> {` so why is it only expecting types?

Comment: @shane, I updated my answer. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by wrapping `KeyType, Key, Value` in a `template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key, typename Value> struct KeyValue {};` then the `Map` speacialization is `template<typename KeyType, KeyType Key, typename Value, typename..Rest> struct Map<KeyValue<KeyType, Key, Value>, Rest...> {};`

Comment: @shane, You are dropping `Rest` from the specialization. Is that your intention?

Comment: @shane, perfect. It will be good if you can add to your post what your intentions for `Map` and post an answer explaining how you solved it.

Comment: Added solution to question

Comment: naswers do not belong to questions